# Помогите ускорить программу!

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Входные данные
Первая и вторая строки входных данных содержат по одному числу n и m (3 ≤ n ≤ 2×10^9, 3 ≤ m ≤ 2×10^9) — размеры площади.
Третья строка содержит количество имеющихся плиток t, 1 ≤ t < nm.

Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести единственное число — максимальную ширину дорожки, которую можно выложить из имеющихся плиток.

МОЙ КОД

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
t = int(input())
p = (n+m) * 2
x = t
cmt = 0
while x > 0:
    x -= p
    p -=8
    cmt += 1
print(cmt)
```

Comment: Эту программу понять сложно, не то что ускорить. Комментарии уже проходили? Что такое `p` и для чего нужно `p -=8`?

Comment: Вам такие задачи еще рано решать. Начните с простых.

Answer (score 1):

Задача решается в одно действие: делим t на m (или на n, смотря в какую сторону дорожка) и берем от результата целую часть. Это и есть решение.